# Salvar relacionamentos no banco - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Qual a forma correta de salvar dados relacionados no Laravel 5.2?
Tenho uma pequena aplicação onde necessito cadastrar dados de uma empresa e seu respectivo endereço. Ao tentar salvar os dados recebo o erro:

**TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:**

Porém eu já defini o Token na view. No controller eu utilizei Request::all() duas vezes, para salvar a empresa e para salvar o endereço. Está correto?

***Seguem Códigos:***

## MODEL EMPRESA

```
class Empresa extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table   = 'empresas';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = array(
        'razao_social', 
        'nome_fantasia', 
        'cnpj', 
        'tipo_empresa',
        'tipo_cobranca',
        'telefone',
        'email',
        'numero_colaborador',
    );

    public function enderecos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SGW\Endereco');
    }
}
```

## MODEL ENDERECO

```
class Endereco extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table   = 'enderecos';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = array(
        'cidade_id',
        'estado_id',
        'empresa_id',
        'endereco', 
        'numero', 
        'complemento', 
        'bairro',
        'cep',
        'tipo',
    );

    public function empresas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SGW\Empresa');
    }
}
```

## EMPRESASCONTROLLER

```
 public function store()
    {
        $empresa = Empresa::create(Request::all());
        $empresa->enderecos()->createMany(Request::all());

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Empresa ' . Request::input('nome_fantasia') . ' cadastrada com sucesso!');
        return redirect()->action('EmpresaController@index');
    }
```

## VIEW

```
@extends('layout.index') 
@section('titulo', 'CADASTRO DE EMPRESAS') 
@section('conteudo')

<div class="box-header with-border">

  <!-- Exibe a mensagem de retorno (Create, Update, Delete) -->
  @if(Session::has('flash_message'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Sucesso!</h4>
    {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
  </div>
  @endif


  <a href="{{ action('EmpresasController@index') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Lista de empresas
  </a>

</div>

<div class="box-body">

  <!-- form start -->
  <form action="{{ action ('EmpresasController@store') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal  padding-left">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />

    <div class="box-body col-xs-6">
      <br />

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <label for="razao_social">*Razão Social</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="razao_social" value="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <label for="nome_fantasia">*Nome Fantasia</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_fantasia" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="cnpj">*CNPJ</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cnpj" data-inputmask='"mask": "99.999.999/9999-99"' data-mask>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="tipo_empresa">*Tipo Empresa</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="tipo_empresa" name="tipo_empresa">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Empresário Individual">Empresário Individual</option>
            <option value="Microempreendedor Individual">Microempreendedor Individual</option>
            <option value="Sem fins lucrativos">Sem fins lucrativos</option>
            <option value="Sociedade Anônima">Sociedade Anônima</option>
            <option value="Sociedade em Comandita Simples">Sociedade em Comandita Simples</option>
            <option value="Sociedade Empresária">Sociedade Empresária</option>
            <option value="Sociedade Limitada">Sociedade Limitada</option>
            <option value="Sociedade Simples">Sociedade Simples</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="tipo_cobranca">*Tipo Cobrança</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="tipo_cobranca" name="tipo_cobranca">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Adiantamentos">Adiantamentos</option>
            <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="Depósitos">Depósitos</option>
            <option value="DOC">DOC</option>
            <option value="Duplicata">Duplicata</option>
            <option value="Ficha de Compensação">Ficha de Compensação</option>
            <option value="Ordem de Pagamento">Ordem de Pagamento</option>
            <option value="TED">TED</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="email">*E-mail</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="telefone">*Telefone</label>
          <input name="telefone" type="tel" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 99999-9999"' data-mask>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="numero_colaborador">*Nº Colaboradores</label>
          <input name="numero_colaborador" type="number" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body col-xs-1"></div>

    <div class="box-body col-xs-5">
      <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <label for="address">*Endereço</label>
          <input id="endereco" name="endereco" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label for="numero">*Número</label>
          <input id="numero" name="numero" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="complemento">Complemento</label>
          <input id="complemento" name="complemento" type="text" class="form-control ">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="bairro">*Bairro</label>
          <input id="bairro" name="bairro" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label for="cep">*Cep</label>
          <input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "99999-999"' data-mask>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <label for="estado">*Estado</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="estado_id" name="estado_id" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            @foreach ($estados as $e)
            <option value="{{$e->id}}">{{$e->nome}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <label for="cidade">*Cidade</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="cidade_id" name="cidade_id" required>
            <option value="">Selecione um Estado...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="emp" id="tipo" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->

    <div class="box-body col-xs-12">
      <br />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" data-loading-text="Cadastrando...">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i> Cadastrar
      </button>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
@stop @section('post-script')
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select[name=estado_id]').change(function() {

    var idEstado = $(this).val();
    $('select[name=cidade_id]').empty();
    $('select[name=cidade_id]').append("<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Carregando...</option>");

    $.get("create/cidades/" + idEstado, function(cidades) {

      $('select[name=cidade_id]').empty();
      $('select[name=cidade_id]').append("<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Selecione uma cidade</option>");

      $.each(cidades, function(key, value) {
        $('select[name=cidade_id]').append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.cidade + '</option>');
      });

    });
  });
</script>
@stop
```

Alterei o **store()** de EmpresasControler para:

```
public function store()
{
    $endereco = new Endereco();
    $endereco->endereco    = Request::input('endereco');
    $endereco->numero      = Request::input('numero');
    $endereco->complemento = Request::input('complemento');
    $endereco->bairro      = Request::input('bairro');
    $endereco->estado_id   = Request::input('estado_id');
    $endereco->cidade_id   = Request::input('cidade_id');
    $endereco->cep         = Request::input('cep');
    $endereco->tipo        = Request::input('tipo');


    $empresa = Empresa::create(Request::all());
    $empresa->enderecos()->save($endereco);


    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Empresa ' . Request::input('nome_fantasia') . ' cadastrada com sucesso!');
    return redirect()->action('EmpresasController@index');
}
```

Funcionou mas não acredito que seja o jeito mais correto de se fazer.

Comment: Experimentou imprimir os dados do request? faça um `dd(Request::all());` na abertura da função `store()` do EMPRESASCONTROLLER

Comment: Já sim @Miguel, aparentemente está tudo ok. Percebi que os dados da empresa estão sendo armazenados no banco, já os do endereço não, ocorre o erro: _**ErrorException in HasOneOrMany.php line 310:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::create() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\SGW\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php on line 335 and defined**_

Comment: O problema está em sua view... está com três colchetes... ***{{{...}}}*** no token. Coloque apenas **{{ csrf_field() }}** ou deixe dois colchetes assim: **<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />**. Deverá funcionar. Abs

Comment: Certinho @Evert. Retirei os colchetes conforme me falou. Também tive que trocar o createMany por apenas create. Agora deu certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo você pode inseri da seguinte forma:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     try{
       \DB::transaction(function() use($request){

         $campos = $request->only([
            'nome_fantasia',
         ]);

          $endereco = $request->only([
          'endereco',
          'numero',
          'complemento',
          'bairro',
          'estado_id',
          'cidade_id',
          'cep',
          'tipo',
        ]);

         $empresa = Empresa::create($campos);

         $endereco['empresa_id'] =  $empresa->id;

         $endereco = Endereco::create($endereco);
     });

     Session::flash('flash_message', 'Empresa ' . $request->get('nome_fantasia') . ' cadastrada com sucesso!');
     return redirect()->action('EmpresaController@index');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
     return $e->getMessage();
   }

}
```

Você não passou o objeto request como parâmetro do seu método store.

```
public function store(Request $request);
```

Você utiliza `Request::all()` para empresa e também para o relacionamento. Será que não está tentando inserir dados da tabela empresa na tabela endereços não?

Note que eu utilizei o `DB::transaction();` para executar o rolback no banco caso ocorra algum erro. Assim não corre o risco de inserir o empresa e não inserir o endereço.